# How to determine (via php) if site is using a static home page?

Tags: theme-development

I have a script that needs to know if the site is using a static home page. In other words, at "Settings > Reading > Front Page Displays > a Static Page *_*_"

Is there a a get_option() or method call that can be used to determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_option( 'page_on_front' );
```

If this value is not `0`, there is a static page.

Additional note from Johannes Pille:

```
get_option( 'show_on_front' );
```

… returns `post` or `page`. But be aware of [custom post types as front page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=custom%20post%20type%20as%20front%20page).

A good way to find common options is to visit the (hidden) page `wp-admin/options.php`.

Comment: Alternatively, `get_option( 'show_on_front' );` returns either *posts* or *page* (string). Actually, I am not certain, if 'page_on_front' gets set back to *0* if it had been set before and 'show_on_front' is reverted back to *posts* later. Are you?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that 'page_on_front' does get set back to 0 when changed and 'show_on_front' also gets changed back to posts as well.